# VBA set cmd result as string and strip it

Tags: regex, vba, shell, cmd

I know there are some posts about this already but I'm trying to use the `whoami` function within `shell` and it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm wondering if this is the right way to capture the result from the cmd execution or if I'm doing it all wrong.

```
Dim UID as String 
Dim PID as Variant 

PID = Shell("cmd /k whoami" , VbNormalFocus)
UID = Right(PID, Len(PID) -10)
```

The whoami expression gives me `Business1\MyID02` and I want the UID to be just the `MYID02` portion

Comment: I'd use `cmd /C whoami` not to leave an open console window behind…

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the return by "\" and get the second value.

```
Dim UID as String 
Dim PID as Variant 

PID = Shell("cmd /k whoami" , VbNormalFocus)
UID = Split(PID, "\")(1)
Debug.Print UID
```

It should print

```
MyID02
```

Comment: I'm getting error 9 for subscript out of range. Is there a reason for the (1)?

Comment: In a zero based array, `1` is the second item. You will get an error if `PID` does not have a \ in it.

Comment: Is it an issue that it also puts out `C:\Users\UserId\Documents` in the second line of the command window upon executing

Comment: I have no idea. Your question was about how to get the second part of the `whoami` return. I just added to your existing code that I assumed was already working.